Failed processing YAML file - Nav2 Bringup
The get the error when i launch the nav2 bringup_launch.py using the following cmd:

ros2 launch nav2_bringup bringup_launch.py
params_file:=/workspaces/irobot_workspace/src/create_robot/create_bringup/config/create_navigation.yaml
use_sim_time:=True
map:=/workspaces/irobot_workspace/src/create_robot/create_bringup/maps/my_map.yaml

Failed processing YAML file /workspaces/irobot_workspace/src/create_robot/create_bringup/maps/my_map.yaml at position (-1:-1) for reason: bad file: /workspaces/irobot_workspace/src/create_robot/create_bringup/maps/my_map.yaml

Here is my YAML file:
image: "my_map.pgm"
mode: trinary
resolution: 0.05
origin: [-0.95, -0.9, 0]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.25

Thanks for the help

In the config file: sim.yaml, you need to put your home directory. So it should be '/home/YOUR_USERNAME/workspaces/irobot_workspace/src/create_robot/create_bringup/maps/my_map.yaml'

ALSO NO QUOTES for the image

I don't see anything that immediately causes me to say "ah ha!", but here's a working example: https://github.com/open-navigation/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bringup/maps/turtlebot3_world.yaml
Maybe the quotes or the origin angle isn't a float? Not sure.
